# In Eclipse while adding Tomcat 7 server name error

Tags: android, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I am trying to add Tomcat server  in my Eclipse in Ubuntu. When I click "Add new server" in Eclipse and select "Tomcat v7.0 Server", the field "Server Name" is blank and I cannot type in anything in that textbox. I have tried all the things but i don't get any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution for this issue and here it is,

Step 1 :- cd ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
Step 2 :- rm org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
Step 3 :- rm org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
.

After completing this, restart your Eclipse.